# Centering a div element

Tags: html, css

I have a container that I would like to center but it does not seem to be working. I have set the margins on the right and left to auto but it is stuck on the right hand side and it is getting frustrating.

```
.music .pane {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 110%;
    background: rgba(240,240,253,0.90);
    padding: 22px 32px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: ` display: inline-block;` ? try ` display: block;` (note: this is a guess, it might not help). Also: can you set us up with a fiddle that recreates the problem? then we can play with it and figure it out :)

Comment: I think that you just need to remove inline-block...

Comment: In addition to removing inline-block, you probably need to set a width value (and not just max-width) in pixels or percentage

Comment: ya inline block was the issue, but I was trying to make the container as small as the largest child inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leave the `div` as a block element.

```
.music .pane {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 110%;
    background: rgba(240,240,253,0.90);
    padding: 22px 32px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codyogden/eLu17a3r/)

Comment: @BrockAmhurst - nope, `max-width` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove `inline-block` to center the div

```
.music {
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 110%;
    background: rgba(240, 240, 253, 0.90);
    padding: 22px 32px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLu17a3r/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a couple changes to your CSS:

```
.music.pane {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 70%;
    font-size: 110%;
    background: rgba(240,240,253,0.90);
    padding: 22px 32px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

This centers the `div` horizontally.